# BeautifulSoup convert Breaks into python newlines

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup, newline

I have html tables with multiple lines of text and data per cell that I'm trying to eventually extract and they use breaks for readability from site they were scraped from. 
Here is an example of one such cell:

```html
<td class="cell">-<br>21%<br>1<br>
<font color="red">5001</font><br>12%
                </td>
```

**How can I convert these breaks into newlines that are compatible with Pandas (i.e there will be a 4 line string seperated by \n)?**

Using this snippet:

```
for cell in soup.find_all('td'):
    cell.replace_with(cell.get_text('\n',strip=True))
```

Results in NaN values for every entry in the table.

Comment: You want the entire string in one Pandas cell?

Comment: I have to match certain lines in each cell with others so i figure that part might be easier to handle with something like an explode in pandas

Answer (score 0):

you can replace `'br'` with `'\n'`:

```
for linebreak in soup.find_all('br'):
    linebreak.replace_with('\n')
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: when I tried this out I did get my strings on new lines but importing into pandas (via read_html) removed all the newline chars